# Spring injected resource is always null

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

**ISSUE:**

I am trying to inject a service into a bean but the service instance is always null.

**BACKGROUND:**

I have two beans one called from the other. This is how they are defined in XML config:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<bean class="com.test.MyBeanImpl" name="myBean"/>
<bean id="myService" class="com.test.MyServiceImpl" />
```

and the beans are implemented like so:

**MyServiceImpl.java**

```
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    public void getString() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

**MyBeanImpl.java**

```
@Component
class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean, SomeOtherBean1, SomeOtherBean2 {
    @Resource(name="myBean")
    private MyService myService;

    public MyBeanImpl() {}
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

Is there some reason related to the fact that my bean implements 3 interfaces that is preventing the Service being injected? If not what other factors could be effecting it?

Comment: Could you post the class declaration for the class you are trying to inject `MyService` and the entire configuration?

Comment: I've updated the OP to include more info. Basically I have no annotations in the MyService interface or implementation class. Cheers

Comment: If your bean configuration file doesn't contain `<context:annotation-config/>` I do not believe `@Resource` will work. See the gist I posted.  I have tested and it works.  If it doesn't meet your needs let me know how your situation differs and I will modify.

Comment: I've updated the OP to be more clear

Answer (score 7, accepted):

as you are using annotations Just mark your service class with `@Service` annotation and use `@Autowired` annotation to get the instance of your service class

***MyServiceImpl.java***

```
package com.mypackage.service;
@Service
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

    public void getString() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

***MyBeanImpl.java***

```
@Component
class MyBeanImpl implements MyBean, SomeOtherBean1, SomeOtherBean2 {

    @Autowired  
    private MyService myService;

    public MyBeanImpl() {}
}
```

also make sure you mention your package name in `<context:component-scan />` element in your dispatcher file as

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage" />
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the bean you are injecting `MyService` into is a bean.

```
/* This must be a bean, either use @Component or place in configuration file */
@Component
public class SomeClass{
   @Resource
   private MyService myService;
}
```

Also make sure that within your configuration you have specified that the application uses annotation-based configuration using:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Since your using multiple interfaces it may be best to qualify the bean with a name:

```
<bean class="com.test.MyBeanImpl" name="myBean" />
```

Then specify the name element on the `@Resource` annotation

```
@Resource(name="myBean")
private MyService myService;
```

Here is a [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/kmb385/8429322) that explains these concepts.

Comment: Hi Kevin, firstly thank you for going to the effort of creating the Git Gist. There is a slight difference in that the bean you defined as MyApp is the one that implements 3 interfaces and the MyServiceImpl bean implements one interface "MyService". When I try your suggestions above I now get a deployment error saying that there's no bean called "myBean" because your "SomeClass" is what I call "MyBeanImpl".. I'll update my OP to make it clearer